# Crystals Reports paper height adjustable

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a Crsytal Reports in C++, which is printing a bill in a shop.
Its working,  printer like 80cm paper[Roll paper does not have any fixed height, width is 80cm. Is it possible to adjust the display height? I'm ok at paper width , my problem is paper height.

Comment: Kindly share what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

First you will need the printer you are using installed on the computer where you design the crystal report.  Then in the Crystal Report designer click on File > Page Setup (the path to Page setup could be different if you are using Visual Studio).

Once you are on the Page Setup window for your report, there is a section at the top labeled "Printer Options".  Use the drop-down control here to select the printer for your report.  From here you have two options, results can vary slightly with each option depending upon the drivers used for your printer.  I use Zebra printers though and both options usually work for me.

Option 1.
In the "Print Options" section of the "Page Setup" window in Crystal Report click the check box to "Disassociate Formatting Page Size and Printer Page Size".  Change the drop-down control to "User Defined Size".  Then manually set your Horizontal and Vertical size.  The Vertical Size will be used as a sort of minimum height for the printed report, but if the report grows content in its design the require additional height, it should continue printing beyond the defined page size's Vertical value until all content is printed.

Option 2.
In Windows open Printers & Devices and then open the Printer Properties for the roll-fed Printer you are using.  Go to the "Stocks" tab and setup a label size here with a height and width.  Again, the height will be used as a minimum and the printer will exceed it's value when the report being printed needs to do so.  Once you have created the label in Stocks, return to your Crystal Report Designer and go back into Page Setup again.  Ensure your roll-fed printer is still selected in Printer Options, then ensure the check box to "Disassociate Formatting..." is UNCHECKED.  When this option is not checked the drop-down control will allow you to select a page size from the list of labels/page sizes defined in the Stocks tab of the Printer Properties from earlier.  Select the stock you setup earlier, and then click "OK" to finish.

At this point you should be able to print your report to a roll-fed printer without any problems.  However, not all printers are equal in this regard.  Crystal Report relies upon the printer having properly supported drivers for this to work.  Most of the printers I've encountered work well-enough, but I have seen some that have driver problems that prevent them from working.